# Xcode 7 - how to build Release target?

Tags: macos, xcode7

Xcode 7.2 generates output only in the Debug folder when I run **Product -> Build For -> Running**. I'm not able to force Xcode to generate anything in the Release folder.

Also the outline entries under "Products" on the left side also point to /Users/XXX/Library/......./Products/**Debug**/....

How can I generate the **Release** target?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default Profile and Archive build Release, so you could do Build for->Profiling to get a Release build.

You can also modify things to build different configurations, or add your own.  Choose Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme. Then to make Run use the Release configuration, select Run on the left side and choose Release for Build Configuration on the right.

Comment: Great, thank you for the Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme hint.

I have an embedded target in my product, a "Login item helper" (as described by MartianCraft here: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/01/login-items/) linked to my application thru Build Phases -> Copy Files. Can I verify somehow that this application is also compiled as Release? Is there a way to verify it just in case? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 8):

Choose Product -> Archive. That is a Release build. Now you can export as a Mac OS X app.